# In Power Automate flow, choosing 'Suspended' as the 'Status Reason' in the 'Update a row' action on the 'Approvals' table causes error

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I am testing what the behaviour is when choosing different `Status Reason` options in the `Update a row` action on the `Approvals` table.

When choosing the `Suspended` option, I am getting the following error message from the action in the Power Automate flow:

> 192350002 is not a valid status code for state code msdyn_flow_approvalState.Inactive on msdyn_flow_approval with Id *****

I have tested these other `Status Reason` options and they do not produce an error:

- Abandoned
- Cancelled
- Expired

The reason I am testing the behaviour of these `Status Reason` options is that I want to 'cancel' the Approval Request when it times out, but I would like to be able to differentiate between when a user has manually cancelled the Approval Request, and when the 'Update a row' action in the flow has cancelled the request because the Approval Request has timed out.

To clarify, the reason I want to differentiate the scenarios is so that we (as admins), and the end user/s, can easily see when an Approval Request was :

- cancelled by the user
- cancelled by the flow (after the request timed out)

Currently, the adaptive card in the email notification and the notification in teams don't make this differentiation clear - in teams it just displays that the request was cancelled by the user that originally requested it.

**Action:**

Update a row (Dataverse)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/#update-a-row

**Steps to recreate:**

Create a manually triggerred Power Automate flow.

Add the following actions:

- Create an approval
- Wait for an approval
- Current time
- Update a row (Dataverse)

Set the 'Update a row' action as follows:

Table name:  Approvals
Row ID:  (pass in the Approval ID from the 'Create an approval' action)
Stage:  Complete
Status Reason:  Suspended <---------------- choosing this option is causing the error
Completed On:  Current time
Status:  Inactive

I've looked for a comprehensive list of valid `Status Reason` codes and what they mean, but can't find it.

You would think `Suspended` should be valid, because it is an 'out of the box' option.

Possibly a bug?